# T-SQL: A list of Date without using temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have a table

> |Start Date|End Date  |Value|Avgerage Value Per Day|
>
> |2011-01-01 |2012-01-01| 730 |   2|

I want to turn this table into a `View`

> |Date|    Average Value |
>
> 2011-01-01 |  2
>
> 2011-01-02 |  2
>
> 2011-01-03 |  2
>
> .....
>
> 2011-12-31 |  2

Is is possible without using temp table to generate a list of date?
Any ideas?

**Edit**

Thanks both of the answers

`With`   **recursive view** is similar as temp table

I do worry about the performance in a view, caz the view later will be involved in other processes.

I'll try recursive view then, if it doesn't fit, I may just use an **hard code date list table**.

Comment: looks like a question just asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532462/create-a-select-statement-with-a-group-by/10532543#10532543

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. This generates the days from the input set and then gives you the ranges you need

Though this technically internally is like temp tables you can create a **recursive view** :

```
Create View TestView as
    with Data As -- Pretends to be your table of data replace with  select from your tables
    (
        select Cast('2012-05-01' as DATETIME) [Start Date], Cast('2012-05-02' as DATETIME)  [End Date], 2  [Avgerage Value Per Day]
        union all
        select Cast('2012-04-01' as DATETIME) [Start Date], Cast('2012-04-05' as DATETIME) [End Date], 3  [Avgerage Value Per Day]
    )
    ,AllDates as -- generates all days
    (
         select cast('1900-01-01' as datetime) TheDate
         union all
         select TheDate + 1
         from    AllDates   
         where   TheDate + 1 < '2050-12-31'
    )
    select TheDate [Date], o.[Avgerage Value Per Day]
    from    AllDates
    join Data o on TheDate Between o.[Start Date]   AND   o.[End Date];
```

you can the query it  but you need to ensure that you specify a recursion limit

```
select * from TestView
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

this gives this result

```
Date                        Avgerage Value Per Day
2012-04-01 00:00:00.000 3
2012-04-02 00:00:00.000 3
2012-04-03 00:00:00.000 3
2012-04-04 00:00:00.000 3
2012-04-05 00:00:00.000 3
2012-05-01 00:00:00.000 2
2012-05-02 00:00:00.000 2
```

You can see that from the test data I wanted May 1-2 and April 1-5

Comment: thank u, pls see my edited question. What is you suggestions to performance issue. is recursive still good?

Comment: The recursion is only to get 'all the dates in the range you're interested in'. It's not recursing your tables. You can update the alldates query to limit the dates to the min and max from your table, but I don't see it as an issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @start datetime
SET @start = '20110501'
declare @end datetime 
SET @end ='20120501'

;with months (date)
AS
(
    SELECT @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,date)
    from months
    where DATEADD(day,1,date)<=@end
)
select * from months OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

[image]

etc..etc..etc..

Comment: How is this a view, all it does is produce set of dates?

Comment: @PreetSangha I wrote the solution of creating those dates without tmp table. `Is is possible without using temp table to generate a list of date?` .you didnt renew - anything in your answer. ( excpet adding it to a a view)

Comment: thank u, pls see my edited question. What is you suggestions to performance issue. is recursive still good?

Comment: Just be careful.  SQL Server has a limit on the depth of recursion.  You need to be aware of the OPTION (MAXRECURSION <n>).